# Adding double quotes to multiline variable in pipe in Bash

Tags: bash, pipe, pipeline

I have a multiline variable in a variable, such as

```
This is
a variable
```

It goes through multiple piped commands and at some point, I want to add it double quotes, so it becomes

```
"This is
a variable"
```

I tried to use `awk` and `print` to do that, as I found some answers online and in here, but it either prints nothing, prints the name of the variable or just `"This`. Here's what I got:

```
    echo $list_comments \
    | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (l=1; l<=n; l++) print a[l]}' \
    | awk '/'$FILTER_COMMENT'/ {print $0}' \
    | cut -d ":" -f2 \
    | sed -e 's/[\"]/''/g' \
    | tr "\n" "\r" \
    | awk '{echo "\"$1\""}' \
    | tr -d "\n" >> app_comments.txt
```

If it is relevant, I am trying to create a CSV file, so I need this multiline variable between double quotes to keep it that way. Let me know if there's anything to add.

Comment: "If it is relevant, I am trying to create a CSV file, " ... Yes, very relevant! Better to include 2 lines of sample data, 1 that needs multi line field and 1 that doesn't AND then show how you need it converted. ALSO, All of the cmds you have piped together can be executed as 1 `awk` script BUT there's a lot of crazy stuff in there , `awk '{echo ...}'`???. Finally, did you deliberately leave out dbl-quotes around `"$list_comments"` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I didn't try to leave double quotes as you said, I'll try that! The  `awk '{echo ...}'` is one of my many unsuccessful attempt to add the double quotes to the value. Everything else is just treating a JSON string got from an API.

Answer (score 1):

Is that you expected?

```
$ a=$(echo -e "hello\nword"); echo "${a}"
hello
word

$ a=$(echo -e "hello\nword"); echo \""${a}"\"
"hello
word"
```

Comment: It didn't work, sorry. It doesn't print anything when I tried your way in the `awk '{echo ... }'`

Comment: @Keker mm I'm not sure I've understood clearly your request.. how about this? ```a="123"; awk -v var="$a" 'BEGIN{print "\""var"\""}'```

Comment: Sorry, I can't do it like that, as I'm in a pipe... I can't put anything in `var=...` because of the pipe. Or I don't know how to do it.